# Jssor Image Slider

Tags: jquery, html, image, slider, jssor

I have an image folder in my project. The image slider extracts images from image tag of a particular div, but I do not have any images in my div at compile time.

I am dynamically creating the image tag using a c# function which puts all images from the folder.

How to pass those images to the slider?

Answer (score 0):

Before you initialize a slider, you should get slides html code ready. There are at least 2 ways to reach the goal. See following code examples,

```
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;">
        <!-- approach #1. render slides html code by aspnet program -->
        <!-- approach #2. render slides html code by javascript program -->
    </div>
```